# window.location.href and location.reload() does not load updated page from Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form being updated on AJAX call.

After Ajax call is succeeded, I want to reload that same page to reflect new changes.

I have used `location.reload()` and `window.location.href` after AJAX call is succeeded, a proper RELOAD on browser is performed but the form shows the old data, not new.

If I reload page using browser's reload button the newly updated data is shown.

But how do I reload a page properly using jQuery?

Comment: This sounds like a caching issue. Instead of reloading the entire page can you append the new data to the DOM?

Comment: Are you sure that you are waiting until the AJAX call succeeds? I've previously seen people *start* the call, and then reload the page before it finishes. (The line of code after the AJAX is sent is not when it has finished; you need to use a callback)

Comment: Doesnt seem Cache issue, because I just press simple Reload button in Chrome and new data is reflected, I did not perform HARD REFRESH

Comment: @Katana314 yes I am reloading inside SUCCESS callback

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method  `reload(forcedReload)` accepts a Boolean flag, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

Please try:

```
// Reload the current page, without using the cache
document.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

document.location.reload(boolean) has been deprecated.

Comment: Not really a helpful answer if you don't state the alternative (if there's one) to the question. This would be more suitable as a comment.